# How do I change the deployment path for Linux?

Tags: linux, delphi, deployment, path, delphi-11-alexandria

Using Delphi 11 Alexandria on a Windows 10 PC.  I am deploying to a Cloud "Linux" server.  This works, but the path it uses on Linux is too convoluted and not what I want.

The DocWiki tells me to change the **Remote Machine Information** in the "Connection Profile".  But I am unable to see any such field.

So, how do I change the path on the Linux machine?

Comment: For Delphi 11 use Project -> Deployment, and set the remote path as needed. Note that by default PAServer runs in restricted mode and won't copy files outside of the scratch directory.

Comment: @Brian, if there was such a field to change, I would not be asking the question.  For the project, with Linux set as Target.  Under Deployment there is only subitem "Provisioning" which has two fields Target and Build Type.  There nothing else, certainly nothing with Remote in its name.  Are you saying that you can see this Delphi 11 on your machine ?

Comment: From the Delphi main menu: Project -> Deployment.  Couple entries from the bottom of the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One place to set the target directory for each deployment file is from the Delphi main menu: Project -> Deployment where you can select a given Platform and Release type. Can edit the field directly in the list shown.

[image]

Note that by default PAServer runs in restricted mode and will not place files outside of the scratch directory. Look at the docs for PAServer for the command line parameter to run unrestricted.